# Kotlin/JS web app doesn't start on Heroku

Tags: heroku, kotlin-js

When I start the app, I get error code H14: no web proccess running.

I've already seen this: [Gradle java web app doesn't start on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240657/gradle-java-web-app-doesnt-start-on-)
heroku, and I've tried to run the command, yet I get this error: `couldn't find that process type (web).`

What is going on?

Comment: Do you have a `Procfile`? Are you deploying with Docker?

Comment: I do not have a Procfile. I'm not deploying with Docker. I'm very new to web dev, so please try dumbing things down.

Comment: Have you gone through the Heroku "getting started with Java" tutorial? It [covers the `Procfile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#define-a-procfile).

Comment: I haven't. Thanks! Just to be clear - what command needs to be run to start a Kotlin/JS app?

Comment: I don't know. I've never used Kotlin. How would you run it locally?

Comment: I run the "browserProductionRun" gradle task.

Comment: Maybe you should look at [Heroku's Gradle tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-gradle-on-heroku), too.

Comment: What kind of kotlin/js web app is it? Node? React?

Comment: I believe it's a React web app